# Is there a way update all subclasses of a class in one go with Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I've changed the constructor of a base class and now need to update all subclasses so that they send in the needed dependency to the constructor.
Is there any way to update all the subclasses without opening them all and manually doing this?

I've done this manually.

Comment: I don't think, there is anything _nice and easy_ available. Depending on the count of replaces I would try a Search + Replace maybe even with regular expressions or just do it completely by hand as last option.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is correct. I've tried this "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/change-method-signature?view=vs-2022" and it works to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

what you need:

1. In Visual studio, right click on the base class in the solution explorer.
2. Select Refactor > Replace > Inheritance.
3. In the Replace Inheritance dialog box, select the new base class.
4. Click Replace.

In this way all subclasses are updated to inherit from the new base class

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't changed the base class. Only the constructor of the base class.